# Security Certificate error em WebBrowser

Tags: c#, winforms, navegador-de-internet

Estou trabalhando num programa winforms que basicamente utiliza o `WebBrowser` para acessar o site da receita federal utilizando o certificado digital.

Meu problema é o seguinte, antes de tudo, peguei esse projeto pronto e estou marretando ele conforme as necessidades, ele precisa ser obrigatoriamente acessado pelo IE (não importa a versão),  o acesso é feito de tempos em tempos podendo ficar ocioso por bastante tempo.

Acontece que apos ficar muito tempo ocioso ele cai no error ***Security Certificate*** do IE e não sai mais.

Já tentei fechar a instância, mas acaba sempre pulando algum *popup* do IE e precisando de intervenção do usuário (pra dar o OK na mensagem).

**Obs**.: Já adicionei o site no trust, já adicionei o certificado do site, já estou usando o **`ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true`** e já tentei forçar a navegação para outra página, mas o programa trava. Está configurado no IE para utilizar o certificado digital sem precisar solicitar.

Answer (score 1):

Sites com certificados são complicados para usar com webbrowser. Quanto me deparei com esse problema, inicialmente, resolvi fazendo uma thread para monitorar quando a janela do certificado aparece e jogar um ENTER no tecla. isso funciona somente quando tem 1 certificado, porém, a janela não pode perder o foco.

A solução ideal serial usar httpwebrequest.